# FME transform query result to JSON and then XML

Tags: postgresql, fme-form, json, xml

I execute query on my postgresdb to get result as a json: description is here http://rextester.com/ZULI42144

It looks nice but now I would like to convert it to xml. I decided to use fme to query postgres just like in example and now I have noe idea how to convert the result to xml and write it to file.

Also talking about json which I also need (I need result in JSON and XML format) what I achieved is that I simply executed postgres query end then wrote results using simple text writer so I suppose that fme doesnt really know that the query result is a JSON :)

Comment: What do you need the xml file for? A web app?

Answer (score 1):

I think the better idea would be to query the postgres db directly with FME, rather than submitting a query that returns JSON. Because a direct JSON to XML conversion - once you're already in the workspace - is going to be complex. Better to just read the postgres as "FME features" and convert them to XML.

Once you have that, just add an XML writer (or a FeatureWriter transformer). That will write XML output for you. If you need a specific schema then set that in the writer parameters, along with any other settings, stylesheets, etc.

I made a quick movie demo here: https://www.screencast.com/t/Sb0jAxSFOh

Comment: Forgot to mention, there's also a ton of XML examples on the FME knowledgebase at: https://knowledge.safe.com/search.html?f=&type=kbentry&c=&redirect=search%2Fsearch&sort=relevance&q=xml